# Що означають слова "пся крев" та "Кров би тебе нагла заллєла"

Tags: ненормативна-лексика

Натрапила на доволі цікаву і головне веселу статтю [Про галицькі матюки](http://www.dubrova.if.ua/pro-galitski-matyuki/). Трішки насміялася і водночас виникли деякі питання: а що ж означає прокльон "Кров би тебе нагла заллєла" і матюк "пся крев"? Вкінці статті наведено словничок, але саме цих виразів немає.

До речі, колись чула від одного старожила на Перемишлянщині, що коли він чхнув, то одразу ж приповідав: "Ех, пся крев", тільки пояснити значення того виразу він не зміг, лише віджартовувався. То яка ж семантика закладена у цих виразах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«Пся крев» – це [запозичення](http://www.i-franko.name/uk/Folklore/1895/PsjaKrevIPesjaVira.html) з польської, від «psia krew», «собача кров». Тут кров значить «потомство», то й весь вислів значить щось на кшталт «сучий син».

Про наглу кров і так зрозуміло, [«нагла» значить](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghlyj) «раптова, несподівана, непередбачена».

Comment: Про наглу кров мені від початку якраз найменше було зрозуміло. Типу, походить від побажання хвороби/поранення (щось на зразок «бодай би тебе кров залила [твоя]»)?

Comment: @Sasha - Так. А хіба ще якось можна зрозуміти?

Comment: Ну, до Вашої відповіді я взагалі не знав, як це розуміти (і чекав відповіді перш за все саме на цю половину питання); але Ваша відповідь якось підштовхнула мою думку у правильному напрямку.